# R h2o.glm - issue with max_active_predictors

Tags: r, h2o

I wanted to estimate h2o.glm model with pre-defined maximum number of active predictors (non-default max_active_predictors column). Here is the example:

```
set.seed(123)

par1 <- matrix(c(100, 200, 300, 400, 40, 30, 20, 10), 4, 2)
par2 <- c(1000, 2000, 3000, 4000)

coef <- c(0.5, -0.5, 1, -1, 1.5, -1.5, 2, -2)

mat <- as.data.frame(cbind(apply(par1, 1, function(x) rnorm(1000, mean = x[1], sd = x[2])),
                           sapply(par2, function(x) rpois(1000, lambda = x))))
mat$Y <- as.numeric(t(coef %*% t(mat)))

h2o.init(nthreads = -1)
mat_h2o <- as.h2o(mat, "mat.h2o")

glm_base <- h2o.glm(x = setdiff(colnames(mat), "Y"), 
                    y = "Y",
                    training_frame = mat_h2o,
                    solver = "IRLSM",
                    family = "gaussian",
                    link = "family_default",
                    alpha = 1,
                    lambda_search = TRUE,
                    nlambdas = 10)

summary(glm_base)

glm_restr <- h2o.glm(x = setdiff(colnames(mat), "Y"), 
                     y = "Y",
                     training_frame = mat_h2o,
                     solver = "IRLSM",
                     family = "gaussian",
                     link = "family_default",
                     alpha = 1,
                     lambda_search = TRUE,
                     nlambdas = 10,
                     max_active_predictors = 3)

summary(glm_restr)
```

Summary from glm_base looks exactly how I feel it should (eight non-zero predictors), but the latter is counter-intuitive (also eight non-zero predictors). How I can force the algorithm to restrict the complexity of final model to the predefined number of variables.

Comment: That is the correct option. You didn't get any errors? Can you provide the summary? It may be to do with the solver. I know that IRLSM changes the default max.

Comment: I didn't want to paste summary, because it's too long. I had no error, but the second model returns eight (not three) non-zero coefficients. As far as the solver is concerned, I've read in the documentation that this parameter differs across solvers but only with respect to default value, This souldn't be an issue in this example.

Comment: OK. Well without further information it will be difficult to help you further. You could reach out to the H2O Google Group but they will also definitely ask you for a lot more info.

Comment: Btw, did you run this code on your machine? It's not fully reproducible, since I had a problem with adding seed parameter to glm, but maybe you can tell me if you have 4 or >4 non-zero predictors for glm_restr.

Comment: By the way, re: "had a problem with adding seed parameter to glm,", are you using a recent GLM? I also had this trouble in 3.8.2.*, but it seems to be gone in 3.10.0.* series. (I believe GLM itself is always reproducible (?), but the seed allows things like cross-validation splitting to also be reproducible.)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a bug. (Confirmed, see https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-3455)

When I did `h2o.scoreHistory(glm_restr)` I got:

```
Scoring History: 
            timestamp   duration iteration lambda predictors deviance_train
1 2016-09-21 09:25:29  0.000 sec         0  .46E2          4       9806.688
2 2016-09-21 09:25:29  0.052 sec         0  .17E2          7       1988.941
3 2016-09-21 09:25:29  0.100 sec         0   .6E1          9        294.884
4 2016-09-21 09:25:29  0.153 sec         0  .21E1          9         38.086
5 2016-09-21 09:25:29  0.203 sec         0  .77E0          9          4.919
6 2016-09-21 09:25:29  0.255 sec         0  .28E0          9          0.635
7 2016-09-21 09:25:30  0.307 sec         0   .1E0          9          0.082
8 2016-09-21 09:25:30  0.358 sec         0 .36E-1          9          0.011
9 2016-09-21 09:25:30  0.408 sec         0 .13E-1          9          0.001
```

I.e. the first iteration of lambda search, with a lambda value of 46, seems to have swept past 3 and gone straight to 4.

With that clue, I could get three predictors by skipping lambda search and choosing a lambda of 50:

```
glm_L50 <- h2o.glm(x = setdiff(colnames(mat), "Y"), 
     y = "Y",
     training_frame = mat_h2o,
     solver = "IRLSM",
     family = "gaussian",
     link = "family_default",
     alpha = 1,
     lambda = 50)
```

Outputting `glm_L50` says:

```
GLM Model: summary
    family     link         regularization number_of_predictors_total
1 gaussian identity Lasso (lambda = 50.0 )                          8
  number_of_active_predictors number_of_iterations training_frame
1                           3                    0        mat.h2o

Coefficients: glm coefficients
      names coefficients standardized_coefficients
1 Intercept  -998.311697              -3657.657068
2        V1     0.000000                  0.000000
3        V2     0.000000                  0.000000
4        V3     0.000000                  0.000000
5        V4     0.000000                  0.000000
6        V5     0.000000                  0.000000
7        V6    -0.389528                -17.453935
8        V7     1.014556                 53.969163
9        V8    -1.229969                -81.328717

H2ORegressionMetrics: glm
** Reported on training data. **

MSE:  10921.23
RMSE:  104.5047
MAE:  83.98198
RMSLE:  NaN
Mean Residual Deviance :  10921.23
R^2 :  0.6932398
Null Deviance :35601860
Null D.o.F. :999
Residual Deviance :10921233
Residual D.o.F. :996
AIC :12146.34
```

Comment: Thanks for this workaround. I'd be also grateful for confirming if it's a bug or not and when it is possible to get this issue resolved.

Comment: @user2280549 I added the link to the bug report.